# Different markup for each post format

Tags: post-formats

I use the underscores.me framework and in my content.php (the template displaying the loop of posts) I have the following code:

```
<div class="article-text dot-ellipsis">
    <div class="article-title clickablediv">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
    </div>

    <div class="excerpt-index clickablediv">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"></a>

        <?php the_date(); echo " - ";
        $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
        }
        echo $my_excerpt; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This enables me to style every post. However I want to be able to style each post format differently so that e.g "status" posts and regular posts get different markup. I want to do this without CSS!

I am not sure if this makes any sense but, in other words is there a way to do:

If post format is "status" then apply the following markup -->> Something

If post format is "quote" then apply the following markup --->> Something

and so on... for all the formats available in Wordpress by default.

Comment: please please please don't shout. we hear you (aka not blind and being able to read) even when you don't speak in bold

Comment: Sorry about that. I just find it too often that people do not read the whole question and reply with "why don't you just do this and that" when I have already specified this.

Comment: I think the title of the question was explicit enough and didn't need the additional emphasize ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need a specific HTML structure let's keep things clean and do what [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format#Example) suggests - break it into template parts based on the post format. Let's create a subfolder in your theme to store these post formats, maybe `POST_TYPE_SLUG-formats` so it's clear what is in this folder ( Replace the uppercase with your actual post type slug ). Then we can store file in this folder like `format-aside.php` with all the markup you need.

Finally, our loop would look like this:

```
<?php
    if( have_posts() ) {
        while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $format = get_post_format();
            $format = ( FALSE !== $format ) ? $format : 'default';

            get_template_part( 'POST_TYPE_SLUG-formats/format', $format );
        }
    }
?>
```

IF our post type was just the built-in `post` we would have a subfolder in our theme called `post-formats` and inside a few format files like: `post-formats/format-aside.php` and `post-formats/format-chat.php`. In the case that, for whatever reason `get_post_format()` fails and returns `false` it's probably a good idea to add `post-formats/format-default.php` as a fallback.

In your format file you have full access to the loop functions like `the_content()` and `the_title()`.